# Esp32 joystick mouse

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32, joystick

I am using the Esp32 nodemcu to create a Bluetooth mouse controlled by a joystick. The connection is established and I am able to move the mouse, however, I am having issues with the accuracy of the movement. In two of the axis (down and left) the mouse moves diagonally. If you have any suggestions please let me know. Your support is greatly appreciated :).

Here's is my code:

```
#include <BleCombo.h>



int horzPin = 32; // Analog output of horizontal joystick pin

int vertPin = 33;

int lastDebounceTime=0;



signed char limit_xy(int const xy)

{

if (xy < -127) return -127;

else if(xy > 127) return 127;

else return xy;

}



int vertZero, horzZero; // Stores the initial value of each axis, usually around 512

int vertValue, horzValue; // Stores current analog output of each axis

const int sensitivity = 200; // Higher sensitivity value = slower mouse, should be <= about 500

void setup()

{

Keyboard.begin();

Mouse.begin();

Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(horzPin, INPUT); // Set both analog pins as inputs

pinMode(vertPin, INPUT);

delay(1000); // short delay to let outputs settle

vertZero = analogRead(vertPin); // get the initial values

horzZero = analogRead(horzPin); // Joystick should be in neutral position when reading these

}



void loop()

{

if(Keyboard.isConnected()){

if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > 20) {

lastDebounceTime = millis();

vertValue = analogRead(vertPin)- vertZero ;

horzValue = analogRead(horzPin)- horzZero ;

if (vertValue != 0)

Mouse.move(0, limit_xy(vertValue/sensitivity));

if (horzValue != 0)

Mouse.move(limit_xy((horzValue/sensitivity)*-1), 0); //<<<<<<<

}

}

}
```

Comment: What have you done to try and debug this?  Have you traced the values through from the  `analogRead`  to `Mouse.move`. Would be helpful if you could share that information in your question along with what values you were expecting at each stage.